# How to raise correct exit code with bash --login and pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

(This is a follow up of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72854108/4868875) I asked)

I would like to run a command that combines `bash --login` + pipe (with `pipefail` enabled) and catch the correct exit code, and by correct I mean the one from whatever my command returns. However, the `bash --login` executes `~/.bash_logout` which calls `/usr/bin/clear_console` and this overrides my original exit code (because it fails if I run the command from the first session).

For instance, the following should return exit code 2, but as `clear_console` is called (and failed) it returns exit code 1.

```
$ set -o pipefail; true | bash -e -lxc 'exit 2'; echo $?
+ '[' '' ']'
+ '[' -d /etc/profile.d ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh
+++ /usr/bin/locale-check C.UTF-8
++ eval
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
++ snap_bin_path=/snap/bin
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop ']'
++ snap_xdg_path=/var/lib/snapd/desktop
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
++ '[' 'x5.1.16(1)-release' '!=' x -a x '!=' x -a x = x ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh
++ '[' nl = pt -a en '!=' pt ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/debuginfod.sh ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh
++ '[' tty = wayland ']'
++ '[' -z /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop ']'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ export XDG_DATA_DIRS
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh
++ '[' tty '!=' wayland ']'
++ return
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh
++ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' -o -n '' ']'
++ [[ ehxBc == *i* ]]
++ return 0
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh
++ DEFAULT_XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
++ DEFAULT_XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
++ '[' -n '' ']'
+ unset i
+ '[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
+ '[' -f /home/user/.bashrc ']'
+ . /home/user/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return
+ '[' -d /home/user/bin ']'
+ '[' -d /home/user/.local/bin ']'
+ exit 2
++ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
++ '[' -x /usr/bin/clear_console ']'
++ /usr/bin/clear_console -q
1
```

Things that will work but I don't want to:

- Overwrite the `~/.bash_logout` script: Want to touch the least possible from the remote environment.
- Don't use `--login`: Need to load some environment configurations.
- Remove `pipefail` option: Want to keep the error code which makes the pipeline fail.
- Remove the `-e` option: Want to exit ASAP.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you could replace `--login` by an explicit sourcing of the dot file(s) you need to load? E.g., `bash -e -xc 'source .bashrc; exit 2'`?

Comment: I suspect this is just a quoting issue. `bash -e -lxc 'exit 2'`, not `bash -e -lxc exit 2`.

Comment: I have to say, though, that my general attitude towards dot files is that they should never output to stdout or change the return code, so I don't really like a configuration that violates those rules...

Comment: @chepner no, I just tested, and if `.bash_logout` finishes on a command that fails, you get that exit status instead of your command's.

Comment: @joanis It's still *a* problem; OP said they expect an exit code of 2, but 2 is being treated as the argument that sets `$0` in conjunction with the `-c` option, not the argument to the `exit` command being executed by the shell.

Comment: @Berthin maybe you could change your `.bash_logout` to say `/usr/bin/clear_console -q  || true`. This will not change the visible behaviour, but it should stop overwriting your exit code.

Comment: @chepner My apologies, you are correct, `exit 2` should have been in quotes in the first place, and I've even automatically added those quotes without thinking about them... But once you fix that, OP's problem is still there.

Comment: Why are you trying to execute a login shell in a pipeline? You seem to have a case where there is configuration that is *common* to two different uses of `bash` (as the login shell and as the pipeline component); that should be refactored so that it can be sourced *by* `.bash_login` as well as used by some other non-login shell.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments/suggestions. It was meant to be `'exit 2'` (in quotes). @chepner, you are right, I have a shell wrapper that is used in different environments, and in just one of them I needed to load the environments from /etc/profile (which I took for granted by using a login shell). Part of me was hoping to see a magic option that skips the bash_logout, but I don't think that exists. I see no other solution than modify the environment configurations.

Comment: I must say that I am really surprised that clear_console exit code overrides the previous exit codes, I don't know if that's a bug or just the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

##### My recommended solution

My advice with bash (and other shells) is that your dot files should never mess with STDOUT or the error status from any command. You'll need at least minimal adjustments to that config. I'm not sure you can find a solution that leaves them as is.

My tests show that the simplest you can do is add `|| true` after commands in your `.bash_logout` file, so that the exit status of those shell lines will be 0 even when the command fails.

So, your `.bash_logout` file could look like this:

```
/usr/bin/clear_console -q  || true
```

then it won't interfere with the return status.

##### An alternative

If you really don't want to modify your dot files, you could instead source the one(s) you need in a targeted way:

```
$ set -o pipefail; true | bash -e -xc 'source .bashrc; exit 2'; echo $?
```

outputs `2` after all that debugging output.

This solution should load the config you need (change `.bashrc` to what your need if it's not quite right) but not run the `.bash_logout` file.

##### PS: missing quotes

I'm assuming you've made the correction @chepner mentioned in their comments, and you're really doing `bash -e -lxc 'exit 2'` and not `bash -e -lxc exit 2`.